# Body and Div height/overflow issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, vue.js

I'm working on a project using the Vue.js 2.0 framework and a bit of Bootstrap 3. This project has required me to work more on the front-end than I am normally used to so I was wondering if anyone here could give me some useful insight into a few CSS issues I appear to be having.

The Project can be found here: http://rgmotorhomehire.com/project

If you give the source a quick inspection, you will probably notice that the body element is only the height of the navbar, and that the container div's for my various 'Pages' are actually totally outside of the parent body element.

**The main thing I'd like to know is:**

- How I can force the Body to 100% height via CSS, so that it wraps it's child elements properly, and I can then add a Footer to the HTML.

Please note that I have already tried:

```
html,
body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}
```

However, if you try this for yourself in the inspector, you will notice this then introduces a new issue of the HTML element now having an empty space below it.

This whole scenario has left me more than a little lost and confused. Hoping someone out there can inform me on whats causing my issues.

**Note:** I'd like to apologise in advance for any pointless info this post contains (including this note), I've had complaints in the past about my questions not being direct enough but I've tried my best to be as clear and concise as possible, Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Literally straight after this post, I discovered the solution is to use clearfix on my wrapper divs as they had a 0 height bug. This post can probably be closed now. I found this solution here: http://www.jqui.net/tips-tricks/css-clearfix/

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

clearfix is a bootstrap class. It clear out all float property. that is right or left.

If you have a div of calling float left property.

for the class pull-right have the property float right. So for the next div we want to clear all the floating property that called before, so we call clearfix it clear all the floating property. so that it works fine.